# using cec-client without reconnect in bash

Tags: linux, bash, hdmi

I try to write a script for my Raspberry to turn on a relay (on gpio) while my tv is powered on. I want to capture the status via HDMI.

I can use the cec-client to get the status from my tv:

```
echo pow 0 | cec-client -s -d 1
```

but it takes a few seconds to complete.

I have write a script to get the status continuous

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
    command="echo pow 0 | cec-client -s -d 1 | grep 'power status' | awk split(\$0,a,\":\");print a[2]}' | sed 's/ //'"
    status=$(eval $command)

echo $status
done
exit 0
```

It takes about 5% CPU and is very slow.

It would be much faster if i connect only once. This is working very fast:

```
(while true ; do sleep 1 ; echo "pow 0" ; done) | cec-client -d 1
```

But how can I take the output to a variable (in a bash script) and use this status?

Or do I have to go another way / other programming language?

[edit]

Having now realized that it is better to program it with c++. 
I've tried a couple of hours but it is very difficult for me to programm in c++. I have ony programmed in VB.net,Java (all with IDE) and a simple things with bash.

I've looked at the source code from cec-client. But i can´t compile it directly. 
So i have found this site: 
[link](https://github.com/DrGeoff/cec_simplest/blob/master/cec-simplest.cpp)

This is a very good working example that i can compile. 
But i dont know how to add the power status request. I think that must be in the main loop at line 106. 
The command would be: `cec_adapter->GetDevicePowerStatus` but i dont know how to use `enum CEC::cec_logical_address` within this code.

Can you please help me with it? It is for me as beginner to difficult to understand this.

Thank you!

[/edit]

[edit2]
How  Ross Ridge already commented...the extension is another question. 
I have now found the solution. And post this only for completeness.

The Example from DrGeoff [link](https://github.com/DrGeoff/cec_simplest/) is very good. If i add before line 107:

`CEC::cec_power_status power = cec_adapter->GetDevicePowerStatus((CEC::cec_logical_address)0);
std::cout << "Status:" << cec_adapter->ToString(power) << std::endl;`
i can read the status from my tv. So the rest is "only" simple c ++ and i can help me out with google.

Thanks for the Help! The question is done.
[edit2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Raspberry-Pi to test it out with, but try this:

```
(while true ; do echo "pow 0" ; sleep 1; done) |
    cec-client -d 1 |
    awk '/power status/ {split($0,a,":"); print a[2]; fflush()}' |
    while read status
    do
         echo $status
    done
```

Part of the trick here is calling `fflush` in the AWK script so that it's output isn't buffered. Otherwise all the extracted status values will accumulate in awk's output buffer until it's full, which will take a long time.

For this to work the output of `cec-client` also needs to be unbuffered. From looking at the source it appears that it's line buffering its output, so it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. But i have problems with this scipt. It runs only once.

Comment: Sorry for my comment above. I have never used the comment function.

Thank you very much for your Answer. But i have problems with this scipt. It runs only once.
   cec-client -s 
is only singe command. But if i remove this, it shows the first status and after a few seconds (or a minute) it shows the status multiple. It is not continuous. 
Without fflush() it shows nothing. 

Sorry, but im to new to linux to understand how the pipes are working.

Comment: If removing the `-s` is  the only change you made then I guess the problem is that `cec-client` is doing some sort of buffering that I was hoping it wouldn't do.

Comment: I have just found this site:
[link](http://www.locked.de/2014/05/30/raspberrypi-weatherstation-the-tv-station-part-iii/)
With this source code:
[link](https://github.com/locked-fg/Weatherstation/blob/master/src/main/java/de/locked/cecclient/CecListener.java)
This is a script written in java. I think that could that could be a option. But i must install java first on the raspberry.
Or is it better to try program it in C (C++) for me as beginner?

Comment: Using C or C++ would make it much easier to use libCEC directly, which is ideally what you should be doing here. The `cec-client`  command is more of a demo or test of the libCEC library, it's not really designed for the purpose you're trying to use it for.

Comment: I have extended the question above. It is very difficult for me to programm C++.

Comment: @Blondie Your extension is another question and should be asked in it's own separate post. Except unfortunately that question is probably be off-topic here as it would be considered too broad.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip. I have answered my  own question in edit. I have accepted your answer. The question is now done. Thank you very much!